# Is @uifabric/build private package?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I would like to investigate possibility of using just-scripts in my project. So for inspiration I've took a look at its use in office-ui-react. However there is not much I can read from it's just.config.json.

```
const { preset, just } = require('@uifabric/build');
const { chain, task } = just;

preset();

chain('verify-api-extractor').after('build');
```

My question is, if all it's build, test, etc. configuration in @uifabric/build preset function? And if so, if it's a public package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of just-scripts here. I realize that documentation may be a bit lacking at the moment - definitely can use help here!

just-scripts github: https://github.com/microsoft/just
documentation: https://microsoft.github.io/just/

I don't recommend taking @uifabric/build as a dependency for another project. I recommend folks to build on top of the just-scripts one:

https://github.com/microsoft/just/tree/master/packages/just-scripts/src/task-presets

These presets are exported by just-scripts, so you can use them as you wish. `task()` can override already defined tasks, so you can feel free to override build, test, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation. One more thing to answer. Just out of curiosity, is @uifabric/build export as public package or it is internal MS thing hosted on private npm repo?

Comment: It isn't published anywhere - we take advantage of lerna's linking to use it everywhere in the repo to build. You could get started with a full monorepo by typing this: `npm init just`